# C++ Is it possible to cout a whole vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I need to cout a vector. Not just an element of it, but the whole thing.
For example std::cout << vectorName;
Something like that, hope it makes sense.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `std::copy` is your friend.

Comment: Seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4850473/2069064

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt God no.

Comment: `std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, " "));`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either define a utility function like

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& output, std::vector<T> const& values)
{
    for (auto const& value : values)
    {
        output << value << std::endl;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Or iterate yourself

```
for (auto const& value : values)
{
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible - if you define operator<< for your vector. Something like this:

```cpp
#include <iterator>

template <class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const std::vector<T>& container) {
   out << "Container dump begins: ";
   std::copy(container.cbegin(), container.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, " " ));
   out << "\n";
   return out;
}
```