# Macro for push_back giving problems

Tags: c++

I am starting to code in c++.
I was learning macros when this happenned:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

#define PB push_back

int main() {
  vector<int> hello;
  hello.PB(3);
  hello.PB(2);
  cout << hello < "\n";
}
```

My compiler shows, pointing to line 3:

Error: statement cannot resolve address of overloaded function

Comment: First of all never write shortening macros like that. It doesn't make the code "better", quite the opposite. Secondly please [edit] your question to include a proper [mcve], and add a comment in the source on the line where you get the error. And also include a *full* and *complete* copy-paste (as text) of the error output.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What is line 3? If I count correctly in the shown code line 3 is empty. The problem is either the missing overload for `operator<<(ostream &,vector<int>)` (see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785418/c-is-it-possible-to-cout-a-whole-vector?noredirect=1&lq=1) or the missing overload for `operator<(vector<int>, const char[])` caused by a typo (`<` should be `<<`).

Comment: Following up on the comment by @churill, did you (gabrupro) actually *read* the full and complete error message?

Comment: Yeah, it probably complains on attempt to `cout` a vector object

Comment: @churill The "shift" operators have higher precedence so it would really be `operator<(std::ostream&, const char[])`. Not that it really matters much in this case though. :)

Comment: Fixing the markdown of your code I found that hair-raising `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
` . Please don't. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but if you're just starting out in C++ you need to learn good habits. Get rid of that `#include`; replace it with `#include <vector>` and `#include <iostream>`. Get rid of `using namespace std;`. Get rid of that macro. The code in the body of `main` should be `std::vector<int> hello; hello.push_back(3); hello.push_back(2); std::cout << hello[0] << ' ' << hello[1] << '\n';`.

Comment: Also, as a beginner, you don't need to be "learning macros". Don't use them.

Comment: Actually, I don't aim to improve my coding style here. I know we don't use such things in development type of coding, but I am aiming for competitive programming which asks for <bits.stdc++.h> and macros. Shoulda added this is the OP

Comment: And yes, this was the full error message...I didn't copy and paste it but I wrote it verbatim, except the first e in Error, which should have been lower case

Comment: Competetive programming doesn't _ask_ for `<bits/stdc++.h>`. It's just that many sites use a toolchain where that file exists and it happens to include a )(/#"¤-load of "useful" headers - most of which you don't need.

Comment: Ok...didn't know about that. And yeah, even the top level competitive programmers in the world use the ```<bits/stdc++.h>``` header. So I don't think it is bad to use it in such an environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your code I get problems with the `<` instead of `<<` and what I assume the main problem:

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::vector<int>’)
   cout << hello << "\n";
```

It is telling you that there is no known way to output a whole vector to `cout`.

The simple way to fix that is

```
cout << hello[0] << " " << hello[1] << "\n";
```

This gets you an output of

```
3 2
```

The more complex way, with more convenient result, is to do the overloading yourself accordingly.